# Error : Missing expression oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Consider the following sql query:

```
select count(*) from cycle WHERE (select to_char(STARTTIME_UTC, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) between '2015-03-17 15:55:00' and '2015-03-16 12:15:05'
```

I am trying to convert the date into the required format, but I am getting missing expression error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you use `mysql` or `oracle`?

Comment: It was just a question. You solution for oracle works fine.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't convert the date to a string. You should convert the strings to date:

```
select count(*) from cycle WHERE STARTTIME_UTC between to_date('2015-03-17 15:55:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2015-03-16 12:15:05','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

The error message in your query comes from the select. Yu have to remove it.

Comment: @friendanonymous - `todate` is not supported in `sql server`. Use `Convert` or `Cast` or `Format`

Comment: @NoDisplayName there is no `sql-server` tag in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you will execute the query in `SQL*Plus`, then you will clearly see where the **error** occurs:

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*)
  2  FROM dual
  3  WHERE (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
  4  BETWEEN '2015-03-17 15:55:00' AND '2015-03-16 12:15:05';
WHERE (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
                                                       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression


SQL>
```

So, SQL*Plus clearly shows you the error is in the part `WHERE (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))`.

For any calculations on **DATE** column, you need to leave the date as it is. You use **TO_CHAR** to convert a date into a string to **DISPLAY**. If you have a string, and to do any date calculations, you convert it into date using **TO_DATE**.

Also,

> BETWEEN '2015-03-17 15:55:00' AND '2015-03-16 12:15:05'

will force Oracle to go for an **internal data type conversion**.

You must always convert the string into date explicitly using **TO_DATE** for date calculations. So, to avoid internal conversion, use the below query:

```
 SELECT Count(*)
FROM   cycle 
WHERE  (SELECT To_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) BETWEEN
              To_date('2015-03-17 15:55:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND
              To_date(
              '2015-03-16 12:15:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```